# What if I had no chance to export my collection and postman is reinstalled. Is there any way that I can get my older collection?

Tags: postman

What if I had no chance to export my collection and postman is reinstalled. Is there any way that I can get my older collection ?

Answer (score 0):

There is web version of Postman. If you have used your account for the collections you created, they should be stored in the cloud. Otherwise, I cannot think of any other way I could help you with.

Comment: No I was working offline. No account I had created. May be this is lesson learn for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can export all your collections to a single dump file.

```
General Settings > Data Tab > Download
```

https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/importing-and-exporting-data/#exporting-data-dumps

Comment: I should have done this step before I loosing my data, then I guess this should have worked. Now I have nothing in my postman to take data dump.